# Why is the text in my menu shifted to the right?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm currently setting up a sidebar menu for my Wordpress website. I'm running into 2 issues. The 1st one is that the text in the menu isn't lining up to the left side properly. I have tried to use the text-align attribute but it doesn't work.

The 2nd problem is that there is a bit of random space at the bottom of the menu that I don't know why is there.

Problem is happening here: http://dreamedbig.com/our-services/

[image: Menu shifted right]
**My HTML/PHP:**

```
<div class="page-content">
 <div id="services-menu" class="services-sidebar">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('services'); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#services-menu {
    border: 1px solid black;
    align-items: left;
    float:left;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: #BCE6FB;
}

#services-menu li{
    list-style-type:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#services-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #08203D;
}

#services-menu ul {
}

#services-menu ul li a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    padding-left:   5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

#services-menu ul li a::after
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #00A2DA;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 1s;
    z-index: -1;
}

#services-menu ul li a:hover::after
{
    width: 100%;
}

#services-menu ul li:nth-child(odd) a::after
{
    background-color: #00A2DA;
}

#services-menu ul li:nth-child(even) a::after
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant, rendered HTML. Without seeing what is generated by `dynamic_sidebar('services'); ` we are guessing, or having to go off site to find critical information. The question should contain **all** relevant information, preferably as a [MCVE]. Links to your site can be problematic if you are actively trying to fix the issue as we try to debug it, giving us a moving target.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some inherited styles from classes called `.widget` and there is margin and padding added to `ul`. This is common is your using something like WordPress or underscores that come with some stylesheets.

I think these styles will correct it

```
.widget, #services-menu ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

I found the unwanted margin and padding by using inspect in my chrome browser. I highly recommend it for frontend styling because it makes troubleshooting these kinds of issue easier to resolve.

[Here is an article to better explain how it works](https://zapier.com/blog/inspect-element-tutorial/)

Comment: Inherited styles were the reason for the bottom space. For me though, the left padding was a default little formatting on list-elements done by chrome. To avoid stuff like that, I would advise searching for a reset.css in google, and including it above any other css (though some would say it's an old-fashioned solution). But yeah, it's a great advice to learn using the "Inspect element" function in your browser, it helps with stuff like this immensely. You can also experiment with modifications on the fly. I could never go back to not using it.

Comment: ^ I didn't realize it was caused by chrome. I run into it all the time and ended up working it into my normalizing styles. Thanks for the insight :)

Comment: Okay thanks! That solved both issues. I'll be sure to check out the article.